# Owned data is getting a lifetime

Tags: rust

On the code below, I'm trying to transform a reference to owned data. The method `to_owned` ensures a `'static` lifetime for the new returned type. However, it's complaining that this returned type is not really `'static` because of the `impl <'a>`. I don't see what does `'a` have to do with this since all the returned objects in `to_owned` are `owned` and thus should be `'static`.

```
pub enum RRtspEncodedPacket<'a> {
    Owned(Data<Body>),
    Ref(&'a Data<Body>)
}

pub struct Body(Inner);

enum Inner {
    Vec(Vec<u8>),
    Custom(Box<dyn Custom>),
}

trait Custom: AsRef<[u8]> + Send + Sync + 'static {}

pub struct Data<Body> {
    pub(crate) channel_id: u8,
    pub(crate) body: Body,
}

pub trait EncodedPacket<'a, T: Send>: Send {
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Box<dyn EncodedPacket<'static, T>>;
}

impl<'a> EncodedPacket<'a, u8> for RRtspEncodedPacket<'a> {
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Box<dyn EncodedPacket<'static, u8>> {
        match self {
            Self::Owned(o) => Box::new(Self::Owned(*o.clone())),
            Self::Ref(data) => Box::new(Self::Owned(*(*data).clone()))
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1eafce83690156b9df6432fd7092fec0

Error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:27:40
   |
27 |             Self::Owned(o) => Box::new(Self::Owned(*o.clone())),
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 24:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:24:6
   |
24 | impl<'a> EncodedPacket<'a, u8> for RRtspEncodedPacket<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:27:40
   |
27 |             Self::Owned(o) => Box::new(Self::Owned(*o.clone())),
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `RRtspEncodedPacket<'_>`
              found `RRtspEncodedPacket<'a>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:27:31
   |
27 |             Self::Owned(o) => Box::new(Self::Owned(*o.clone())),
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Box<(dyn EncodedPacket<'static, u8> + 'static)>`
              found `Box<dyn EncodedPacket<'static, u8>>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `to_owned()` you are promising that you will return a `Box<dyn EncodedPacket<'static, u8>>`. But then you are using a `Box<RRtspEncodedPacket<'a>>` to construct the return value; the `'a` may the shorter than `'static`, which is what the compiler is complaining about. This is facilitated by the use of `Self` in `Box::new(Self::Owned(*o.clone()))`. Here, `Self` refers to the type the `impl` block is for, so `Self` is `RRtspEncodedPacket<'a>`; this is how `'a` sneaks into the return type. But what you want is `RRtspEncodedPacket<'static>`. Simply switching `Self` to `RRtspEncodedPacket` - which the compiler will infer to `RRtspEncodedPacket<'static>` - will solve your problem.

Reduced example that compiles:

```
pub enum RRtspEncodedPacket<'a> {
    Owned(u32),
    Ref(&'a u32)
}

pub trait EncodedPacket<'a, T> {
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Box<dyn EncodedPacket<'static, T>>;
}

impl<'a> EncodedPacket<'a, u8> for RRtspEncodedPacket<'a> {
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Box<dyn EncodedPacket<'static, u8>> {

        // Notice: No `Self`, because we go from whatever `Self` is
        // (some `RRtspEncodedPacket<'a>` for some `'a`) to
        // `RRtspEncodedPacket<'static>`.
        match self {
            Self::Owned(o) => Box::new(RRtspEncodedPacket::Owned(o.clone())),
            Self::Ref(data) => Box::new(RRtspEncodedPacket::Owned((*data).clone()))
        }
    }
}
```